# How to check if XmlDocument has changed?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I am conditionally changing an `XmlDocument` in various parts of my code. Instead of passing a "changed" flag around, does the `XmlDocument` object have something built flag for this (like `isDirty`)?

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);

if (...) parent.AppendChild(element);
if (...) parent2.AppendChild(element2);
if (...) parent3.AppendChild(element3);

//METHOD DOESN'T EXIST
if (doc.isDirty())
  doc.Save(file);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although an **XmlDocument** does not expose an **IsDirty** flag, it does have events like **NodeChanged**, **NodeInserted** and **NodeRemoved** which you could use to keep a single flag, which you do not need to pass to any mutation methods:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);

bool changed = false;

XmlNodeChangedEventHandler handler = (sender, e) => changed = true;
doc.NodeChanged += handler;
doc.NodeInserted += handler;
doc.NodeRemoved += handler;

// do some work

if (changed)
    doc.Save(file);
```

Comment: Ah, good spot.  I would still recommend wrapping this up in an object exposing the flag - else your serialisation code is going to also deal with change-tracking on an XmlDocument.  Better to have a specific object to deal with that

Comment: I would add that it's a bit weird/lazy to depend on events to see when the document changes.  You are the one writing the code to change it, after all!

Answer (score 2):

No, XmlDocument stores a document, it does not track changes.  Wrap it in a helper class, set a flag as you describe, or create some other OO structure to work the way you want.

Comment: Passing changed flags around seem like littering. Do you have a suggestion on which way to go?

Comment: You presumably have a clearly-defined class/method for modifying XML, if not, fix that first.  Then there should be a clear, neat place to keep a flag.  If you intend to do it often, derive from XmlDocument (or better maybe XDocument) and implement that functionality neatly.  If you need to store a flag, you need to store a flag..